# Looking for a way to check mathematical operations

Tags: python

I'm looking for any resource to check wether a mathematical expression is correct or not. Maybe a way to input the operation and obtaining a TeX equation as output.

rough example: I'd like to check if

`(lum[i]/(np.pi*radio[i]*(alpha_list[i]*altura_hp[i])**2 *densi[i]*c_p[i]))*(temp[i]/(G*masa[i]))**(1.0/2.0))**(2.0/3.0)`

is the same operation I want to compute. Honestly I feel uncomfortable writing this way coming from TeX.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by correct, but anyway one approach is to compose the expressions using a symbolic computation system and then generating TeX output from that. If you are working with Python, then it's reasonable to try Sympy (https://sympy.org). I'm pretty sure it can generate TeX output. As for myself, I like to work with Maxima (http://maxima.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of working with Maxima. I think Sympy can do more or less the same.

I copied the equation you gave.

```
(%i31) (lum[i]/(np.pi*radio[i]*(alpha_list[i]*altura_hp[i])**2 *densi[i]*c_p[i]))*(temp[i]/(G*masa[i]))**(1.0/2.0))**(2.0/3.0);

incorrect syntax: Too many )'s
asa[i]))**(1.0/2.0))
                  ^
```

Oops, there is a problem with the parentheses. I don't know what you want to do, but for the sake of argument I put in an extra parenthesis to balance it. Now it's at least formally correct:

```
(%i31) (lum[i]/(np.pi*radio[i]*(alpha_list[i]*altura_hp[i])**2 *densi[i]*c_p[i]))*((temp[i]/(G*masa[i]))**(1.0/2.0))**(2.0/3.0);
                      temp
                          i  0.5 0.6666666666666666
              lum  ((-------)   )
                 i   G masa
                           i
(%o31) ---------------------------------------------------
                 2          2
       alpha_list  altura_hp  c_p  densi  radio  (np . pi)
                 i          i    i      i      i
```

Hmm, let's use rational numbers instead of floats for the exponents.

```
(%i32) (lum[i]/(np.pi*radio[i]*(alpha_list[i]*altura_hp[i])**2 *densi[i]*c_p[i]))*((temp[i]/(G*masa[i]))**(1/2))**(2/3);
(%o32) 
                                    1/3
                           lum  temp
                              i     i
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  1/3           2          2                 1/3
 G    alpha_list  altura_hp  c_p  densi  masa    radio  (np . pi)
                i          i    i      i     i        i
```

That looks nice, now let's generate TeX output.

```
(%i33) tex(%);
$${{{\it lum}_{i}\,{\it temp}_{i}^{{{1}\over{3}}}}\over{G^{{{1}\over{
 3}}}\,{\it alpha\_list}_{i}^2\,{\it altura\_hp}_{i}^2\,{\it c\_p}_{i
 }\,{\it densi}_{i}\,{\it masa}_{i}^{{{1}\over{3}}}\,{\it radio}_{i}
 \,{\it np}\cdot \pi}}$$
```

I hope that gives some ideas.